# Adding the header to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with the dimensions `100*512` , I want to process it further in `spark`. The problem with the file is that it doesn't contain header i.e `column names` .  I need these column names for further ETL in `machine learning` . I have the column names in another file(text file). I have to put these column names as headers in the csv file mentioned above.
e.g.

CSV file :-

> ab 1 23 sf 23 hjh
>
> hs 6 89 iu 98 adf
>
> gh 7 78 pi 54 ngj
>
> jh 5 22 kj 78 jdk

Column headers file :-

> one,two,three,four,five, six

I want the output like this :-

> one two three four five six
>
> ab   1   23    sf   23  hjh
>
> hs 6 89 iu 98 adf
>
> gh 7 78 pi 54 ngj
>
> jh 5 22 kj 78 jdk

Please suggest some method to add the column heads to the CSV file.(Without replacing the row of the csv file.
I tried it by converting it to pandas dataframe but can't get the expected output.

Comment: Just write the line containing the headers before feeding csv data to the file. What have you tried?

Comment: what do you mean by _without replacing the row of the csv file_ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First read your csv file:

```
from pandas import read_csv      
df = read_csv('test.csv')
```

If there are two columns in your dataset(column a, and column b) use:

```
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
```

Write this new dataframe to csv

```
df.to_csv('test_2.csv')
```

Comment: Its telling No module named Writer

Comment: I think it’s something to do with the package you are using.   Code mentioned above do not use any package/module named Writer. Can you please send me link to your code?

Answer (score 2):

Unix:

```
cat header_file.csv data_file.csv > data_file.csv
```

Windows:

```
type header_file.csv data_file.csv > data_file.csv
```

Comment: Yes, it is.   There are commas between each header element.

Comment: Speaking of the UNIX part, this results in "input file is output file" message and data_file.cvs will end having only the content of header_file.csv

Answer (score 2):

you can use it :

```
    import csv

    with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
        writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
        writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit a old way ...

**Content of demo.csv before columns:**

```
4444,Drowsy,bit drowsy
45888,Blurred see - hazy,little seeing vision
45933,Excessive upper pain,pain problems
112397013,air,agony
76948002,pain,agony
```

**Content of xyz.txt :**

```
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3
```

**Code with comments inline**

```
#Open CSV file
with open("demo.csv", "r+") as f:
    #Open file which has header
    with open("xyz.txt",'r') as fh:
        #Read header
        header = fh.read()
        #Read complete data of CSV file
        old = f.read()
        #Get cursor to start of file
        f.seek(0)
        #Write header and old data to file.
        f.write(header+ "\n" + old)
```

**Content of demo.csv:**

```
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3
4444,Drowsy,bit drowsy
45888,Blurred see - hazy,little seeing vision
45933,Excessive upper pain,pain problems
112397013,air,agony
76948002,pain,agony
```